# How to set padding for background image in textView?

Tags: android, background-image, textview

I am creating a calc app.
How to set padding to shrink the background image..
I want to convert [image: this backspace background] to something like [image: this]

My xml of TextView :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/c_tv_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/ic_backspace_black_24dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
```

Comment: you can set the image as a drawable , and provide drawable padding to the textview.

Comment: Can understand "set the image as a drawable". Can you give code?

Comment: if you're not showing text, don't use a TextView. Use an ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageView instead and give padding to it :

```
<ImageView
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/product_main_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />
```

and why you need Textview and Background image to that ?
You can simply put `ImageView` or `ImageButton`

Answer (score 0):

You should use imageButton instead of TextView like this:

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/delete_button"
  android:layout_width="70dp"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:background="@drawable/delete_icon"
  android:layout_margin="16"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there's more than one way

**First way**, you have to extends `TextView` into new class and overwrite some `@override` methods. and use this class in `xml`... this is hard way

**Second way** (Recommended), use Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop to adjust a new drawable and make it easily as you like

**Third way**, use `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` and make the background you want in a `Imageview`... easy way and do the job

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:padding="your_padding_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace_black_24dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/c_tv_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```